# JavaScript countdown is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, timer, countdown

I am working a small CodeIgniter project. I am using following javascript countdown which time difference between future date which was stored in server table and web server current time. code is working but I only got 2 second count down and stopped. please some can help me to resolve this issue

```
        <script>
            // Set the date we're counting down to
            var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $time['month']." ".$time['date'].", ".$time['year']." ".$time['hour'].":".$time['minute'];?>:00").getTime();

            // Get today's date and time
            var now = new Date("<?php echo date("m")." ".date("d").", ".date("Y")." ".date("H").":".date("i").":".date("s");?>").getTime();

            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;
            // Update the count down every 1 second
            var x = setInterval(function() {


                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
                document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "";

                // If the count down is over, write some text
                if (distance < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                    document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "none";


                } distance=distance-1;
               
            }, 1000);
        </script>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Is this script inside a PHP for each? Because it doesn't isolate its code so you keep redeclaring all the variables

Comment: yes. code is inside php for each. I copied that part as well. how ever that part erase.

Comment: <?php  foreach ($time_differ as $time):?>

Comment: JS time is measured in milliseconds, so for a working countdown you need `distance = distance - 1000;`. However the main problem is that you're outputting the script multiple times I guess? Because again, you will create multiple lines that start with `var now = ...` but declaring vars twice or more is invalid. Also, you're using getElementById but you cannot use multiple elements with the same id. For one that's invalid HTML, also getElementById  will always return the first one it finds.

Comment: code working fine with distance = distance - 1000; change. Thank you very much for your support

Comment: As long as you only need one, yes. But all of this is outdated and bad practice and should be unlearned

Comment: Here's the proper way to move the data from PHP to JS: https://ideone.com/hMJiYI

Comment: Then you use this: https://jsfiddle.net/60o5huf2/ (fixed PHP: https://ideone.com/BvUPMP)